# Should I do Adidas confirmed in exchange of money

Tags: france, services

Somebody on Facebook asked me to register on the adidas confirmed app and be ready to click tomorrow 4pm so he could get the shoes and, if I am quick enough, he gives me 350€ on Saturday when we go get the shoes (in Paris, I'm French)...

Is this a scam? Should I do it?

Here's the message (translated from French)

- Download the app "adidas confirmed"
- Connect into the app with Xxxx email address and XXXX password
- Modify the info with your real name, and birthdate
- You'll see a white pair of shoes appear, choose them and choose size
  42 (EU)
- Be on the app tomorrow 5 minutes before the reservation opens
- At 4pm a button will appear in the app and you'll need to click it as
  fast as possible
- It'll load for a few seconds and then tell you if you reserved the
  shoes or not
- If yes contact me and we'll go get the shoes in the Marais (place in
  Paris) and I'll give you 350€

Comment: Some people are crazy about shoes, and some shoes are made in a very limited quantity and sell out almost immediately often with a strict limitation of one per customer.  This is probably legit and allows this person to get their hands on more than one pair.  The person probably intends to sell the shoes on the secondary market for far more than the retail price, hence the large payment to you.

Comment: Hoooo okay so I guess I should do it then, that's what I thought to but I also had in mind the fact that he would scam me or like get money from me etc... So should I do it then ?

Comment: Are you connecting with your own email/password that you set up, or his?  Because if it's "his", it almost certainly isn't his, but someone else's entirely.  Somehow, you'll find yourself having used that person's account to buy shoes and being on the hook for the price of the shoes.  On the other hand, if you're using your own login information to buy shoes that some stranger has agreed to buy from you, then that's up to you to decide whether or not you trust it.

Comment: I mean, that's really up to you.  Personally I wouldn't bother with this (or any other harebrained idea) for a stranger, and if it involves fronting the money for the purchase I'd definitely not do it.  And if the reservation is a payment on that account, I'd similarly stay away.  You have no way of knowing the payment method being used is legitimately this person's.  If a close friend of mine thought they could make some money speculating on some limited edition item and I was sure it was all on the up and up, I'd probably do it.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know this guy and the account and password used are some email address he owns

Comment: And as for money, I don't have to pay anything, neither the account, it's in cash in the store, only reservation

Comment: Then, personally, I would stay away because I don't know the guy.

Comment: You posted here asking if this was a scam.  The general consensus is that this is a scam.  You've apparently decided to go ahead and do it anyway.  Please do us a favor and post back here once you find out how the scam works.

Comment: I will, I'll update the post and stuff

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are downloading the app from legit stores [Apple store, Google Play], then it is fine. Adidas is indeed [running a campain](http://www.adidas.com/us/help_app_faqs.html#g01) to get more users download the app and get exclusive shoes that they don't intend to sell in retail market.

The adidas strategy seems to make the product exclusive and available only to individuals. Note you have to be in person and show photo ID at the adidas retail outlet, pay and pick-up the shoes. One can only register once per phone number. The reservation is random, first come first reserved.

The person on facebook is trying to circumvent this by having quite a few people download the app and book. He is then looking at buying this from you. Not sure what would the price of shoes be and is the 350 EUR in addition to the price of the shoes that you need to pay the store.

I couldn't find about Paris, but there were similar campaigns in US last December.

> WHY DO I HAVE TO REGISTER IN THE CONFIRMED APP? In order to have a
>   chance to get a reservation through adidas Confirmed you need to sign
>   up in the app. If you are able to get a reservation, we will use this
>   information (plus your photo ID) to verify your identity when you pick
>   up.
>
> WHAT ARE THE STEPS TO MAKE A RESERVATION?
>   STEP 1: Create an account in the app, verify through SMS, and enable location services and push notifications.
>   STEP 2: Follow @adidasoriginals on Twitter to learn when reservations open.
>   STEP 3: Once the reservation period begins, open the app and navigate to a product page to select your size and confirm your reservation. You must be located within New York City, Chicago, or Los Angeles areas to participate.
>   STEP 4: If you get a reservation within adidas Confirmed you will receive a retail location and timeframe for pickup within the app.
>   STEP 5: Go to the designated location to complete purchase and receive product.

Comment: My concern here is that such campaigns could be used by scammers with fake versions of the software for identity theft, but I'm glad you clarified that Adidas is legitimately running this type of promotion.

Comment: @DanielAnderson Agreed that is the risk if you try and download any random app. The more safety nets are download from proper stores. Be vary of name like apps. There would be tons of look alike apps that can at times confuse individuals. The other aspect in this is if the shoes are priced at 300 EUR and you get 350 EUR, may not be worth the effort and taxi ride to the retail store for 50 EUR.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The app I downloaded is in fact the real one, I'm always careful about it. And yeah I think the guy just wants the shoes really bad he's willing to pay a lot for it... The reservation is happening today at 4pm French time. I'll keep you updated :) thanks ❤

Comment: @juleslasne Just read your comment on email address / password being his. This can be slight cause of concern. Not sure what all this would be used for. It may also simply be he want to track the reservation mail.

Comment: It would be used for my id when I'm going there to pick them um

Answer (score 4):

Definitely sounds like scam. Odds are are high that the page he gave you the link to is a fake and this app is pure identity theft. ***Run away***, unless you are interested enough to do the work to check with the company and confirm this is legitimate.

***Nobody*** contacts strangers with this kind of story without it being a scam. The fact that this one sounds shady is an attempt to keep you from questioning it too closely. Think about it: if it was at all legitimate, couldn't he find a friend of a friend? If it sounds too good to be true, it ain't true.

***Never*** download software unless you know ***exactly*** where it is coming from. It could be anything from ransomware, to something that first steals all you financial info, then uss you mail account to send a similar pitch to all your friends, to a botnet that uses your machine to attack other machines.

Comment: Definitely a scam, but it's not clear who the intended victim is: the OP, or a third party.

Comment: The thing is, I've thought a lot about it and the app is made by adidas... What I think it is is that the guy really wants the shoes and wants to multiply the chances

Comment: @juleslasne - Then why is he insisting you use *his* login details but *your* date of birth? That part makes it sound dodgy to me.

Comment: My date of birth+first name and last name are asked by adidas for the pick up of the snickers in the store to compare it with my id since it's really rare and only one pair per person (80 snickers in the world and I have one)

Answer (score 3):

Any time someone starts asking you to provide personal information, such as a birth date, it could very well be a scam.  This is especially true if it's someone you don't even know.  Be very careful about getting involved in such situations.

There is always some kind of *almost* believable story to what the scammers tell you, and unless you're willing to look deeper into it then it's easy to get pulled in.  On top of that, you have to ask yourself, "why did they pick me for this?", because that's the real question.

You have no idea what *else* the software they're asking you to download might do that you wouldn't know about, but offering to pay you something is a good way for them to get you to bypass your own security by installing it yourself.

If the offer sounds too good to be true or too easy, you have to question it, and in such cases, your best bet is to stay away from it altogether.

Comment: The software is made by adidas and is confirmed to be official on Google play

Comment: @juleslasne - That DOES NOT rule out the possibility of a scram, please think about this more carfeully. You are still giving some random person your personal information and regardless of if they intend to buy shoes they could still also use this maliciously

Comment: I know though the thing is he only has my name, and birthdate. I've thought a lot about it and I don't see any danger. If I succeed to reserve a pair of shoes, I don't have to go get it

Comment: @juleslasne Your name and birthdate are two significant pieces of information. It wouldn't be very hard or expensive to find a likely address for you [at least in the UK it isn't; other countries may vary] especially if he asks you where your nearest store is to pick up the goods. You are setting yourself up for identity theft, even if the other party doesn't have that in mind at the moment.

Comment: This info is asked by adidas so they can verify it on my id when I go pick them up

Answer (score 1):

Alright it's been a little and I just realized I haven't kept you guys updated

Everything went perfectly well. I met the guy I was supposed to meet in front of the store, I queued up with everybody else and the guy handed me discretly 650€. We went in, I bought the shoes, I gave them to him and he stayed inside the store because he was waiting for an uber and outside there was a lot of people who wanted the shoes (80 of them in france) so yeah, I just walked out with 430€ in my walled and here I am, doing perfectly fine with money in my wallet :D End of story, or not because i'll be watching out to other shoes so I can do the same again and apparently 650€ was like waaay underpriced

Comment: Keep in mind this is an exceptional ending to this sort of story.  The way the guy set it up made it sound like a scam.  Most of the time if you suspect something might be a scam, it will be.  Key thing here is that you didn't give out personal info or cash until you were relatively sure everything was ok.  Most of the time things won't turn out this way.

Comment: I know don't worry but yeah I realised that there's a TON of business around those shoes and there was people outside the store who had stacks (yeah literally) of 50€ bills and wanted the shoes so bad

Answer (score 0):

Alright so so far the info I got is the fact that the guy seems to be honests and is a guy who wants to own every snicker he can. He is offering me 650€ for me to pick them up with him. I am going there myself at 3.30pm on Saturday, I'll keep you updated :)